# no implicit conversion over multiple generic constraints

Tags: c#, generics, mono, constraints

Building a piece of C# code using generics I have produced code looking like this:

```
public class Test<U,V,W>
    where U : V
    where V : W
{
    public W Cast(U argument)
    {
        return argument;
    }
}
```

The `return` line fails to compile (under mono 3.2.8.0: "Cannot implicitly convert type U to W"), even though it seems clear that U must be a subclass of W (technically, there might be value types involved, but the above fails even if all three generic parameters are constrained to be reference types). If `U` is constrained to derive from `W` directly, everything works fine.

The above code is trivial to fix (it is enough to insert a cast to V, which of course always succeeds). I have two questions, though: Most importantly, why does the code fail to compile as it is? Links to relevant fragments of C# specs (if any) would be most welcome! Secondly, will a (seemingly redundant) cast to `V` introduce a (useless) type check at runtime?

Comment: 1) most likely because benefit of implementing it is practically zero, 2) compiling into LINQpad and looking at the IL will show.

Comment: That compiles for me. Post the original code!

Comment: Er... it compiles just fine.

Comment: What exactly are you using to build this code? It compiles for everyone who has checked, myself included.

Comment: He must be using an older .NET version

Comment: Which .NET version do you use? In which IDE?

Comment: I am using mono 3.2.8.0, with .NET 4.5 profile. So it seems that it is just a bug in the compiler? (I have added the compiler version to the question)

Comment: What's wrong with the question? Why the downvote(s)? "Works for me" does not seem a good enough reason -- someone else might run into the same error...

Comment: I downvoted and also close voted this question because it is not reproducible. If not reproducible it is not answerable also. After mentioning it is mono, I removed my downvote and retracted my close vote. Care to add these details in your question initially itself. Thanks.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel It certainly is reproducible - you just need the right environment to reproduce it.

Comment: @DStanley I know it is reproducible when right environment is used. But who knows the right environment? You should see the edit history. Op didn't gave any clue about it is all about mono compiler. After a bunch of downvotes and close votes only we OP said it is mono.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that Mono doesn't understand that if U:V and V:W, that U:W.  Try putting that constraint in as well?

edit: I see that you mentioned this in your answer (I missed it).  Since that's the case, I would say it's a bug in Mono.  Just put the constraint in and be done with it?  Maybe submit a bug.